# Why avcodec_encode_video2 generate 0x41 header but not 0x65 as the key-frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

Recently, I used `avcodec_encode_video2` to encode yuv420p to h264 stream.
When I set the `AVCodecContext.gop_size`, the frame header after SPS and PPS is always 0x41.
Only the header of the first frame is 0x65.
`0x41 & 31 == 1`. Is it a key frame?
I feel so strange, could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I find that if I set the `AVCodecContext.max_b_frames=0`, the IDR frame with header 0x65 appears. And if `AVCodecContext.max_b_frames=3`, the IDR frame disappears with 0x41 header instead.
Could anyone explain why? I am a really a fresher for FFmpeg.